# GITWEB - Showing all diffs on a branch

Tags: gitweb

We just implemented gitweb.  On the summary page there is a list of branches.  I am looking to see in one diff all the changes made in a given branch.  I may have made multiple commits in that branch.

If I click that link for the branch in gitweb it takes me to the last commit.  I can do a commitdiff for that diff and keep walking back until the parent is the where I branched off from the master.   However what I really want to do is diff it back to when I diverged from the master in one shot.

I can modify the hp tag in the url to change the source commit.  However that works becauase I know the proper parent commit.  However I would like our QC group to be able to pull up a branch and diff back to where we diverged without them know the actual commit identifiers.   Is that possible?

https://code.dev.company.com/gitweb?p=the/rules.git;a=commitdiff;h=c013f71861af95a43dd0d6587e2d2334ca4baba2;hp=c065c006a02eeb63d8740832c915c0d254081c30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an error on the server set-up